# How can I use Internet connection in Linux having a WinModem. Also, can I Use VS in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, internet, visual-studio

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 9.10. I have couple of questions:

1. How can I use the Internet in Ubuntu 9.10 ? I have a modem driver for XP that does not work in Linux so any tips to get Internet connection working in Linux  ?
2. Is is possible to use Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 or Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in Linux?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://www.superuser.com.

Comment: are you solve it on Stack

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Super user is definitely more appropriate for your question. Though, try to phrase it a little better and with some punctuation.

Comment: i not english well so edit my question

Comment: I think I've got it, @AG, I just wasn't sure about the bit running VS2010 on Linux - not possible if that's what you're asking. The rest I assume is because you have one of those WinModems which are Windows-only. Still this is best over on superuser.

Comment: Didn't get the last of my cleanup edit in on SO (and my rep isn't high enough here) - I gather VWD is Visual Web Developer. So this bod has two problems, a WinModem not working on Karmic Koala and he wants to run Visual Studio tools - hope you guys over here can help.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to Question 1:**

There are drivers for winmodems that work under Linux available from [Linuxant](http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/).

They offer two editions:

- A **free** version (limited to 14.4Kbps data), available at no cost.
- A **full** version (with 56K and FAX), available for a [modest price](https://www.linuxant.com/store/).

I have previously used the free version with Ubuntu 8.04, and had great success!

---

**Answer to Question 2:**

The traditional way to make Windows programs work on Linux is by running them under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

However, Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 probably do not run well under Wine.  In fact, Visual Studio 2008 Professional was given a rating of "[garbage](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=892)" by users and maintainers of Wine.

Perhaps you should consider using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for a .NET development environment for use in Linux.  There are some good [installation instructions](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/dotnet/soa/Gallery-Installing-and-using-mono-on-Ubuntu/0,339028399,339279567,00.htm) available for installing Mono under Ubuntu.

Comment: Updated Question 2 :

You could also use VirtualBox on linux to run what you need,
I use a native VM of windows xp pro sp3 made from my dual-boot partition for now so any change I do is also done in my native install from my dual-boot ...

But you may not need to make a VM from a native installation ...

Comment: Wine? Ugh! I run all my Win apps under VMWare Player. Even the pro version of Wine that I paid for had small but annoying bugs. I prefer to keep my Windows and Linux worlds separate.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible to figure out if your winmodem is supported under Linux if you know exactly what modem chipset you're dealing with.  Some are supported in the standard mainstream distros (Yours apparently isn't one of these).  Some can be got to work with a little work, and still others will never work no matter what you do.  You can get a (somewhat older) [introduction to the issues here,](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Modem-HOWTO-2.html#soft_modem) a good list of pointers for the various chipsets [here,](http://linmodems.org/) and a good comprehensive guide (with help to find out what chipset you have) [here](http://132.68.73.235/linmodems/index.html).

Follow the steps on the last link.  Before long you'll know what chipset you have, and whether you have any hope of Linux support for it.